# Calling Controller DBAction with scheduled Akka Runnable (in Scala / Play 2.2)

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, playframework-2.2, play-slick

I'm attempting to schedule an Akka job when my Play 2.2 application starts.

In it's simplest form, this is what my code looks like:

```
import play.api.Application
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.db.DB
import scala.concurrent.duration._

import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    lazy val database = Database.forDataSource(DB.getDataSource())

    scheduleTheThing(app)
  }

  private def scheduleTheThing(app: Application) {
    Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(1.minute, new Runnable {
      override def run() {
        Logger.info("running the thing!")
        controllers.Application.runTheThing
      }
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm creating a new `Runnable` that will be executed 1 minute after the application starts. `Logger.info("Running the thing!")` gets executed just fine... I'm able to see "Running the thing!" in the application log 1 minute after starting the server. However, `controllers.Application.runTheThing` doesn't seem to get called:

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def runTheThing = DBAction {
    implicit session => {
      Logger.info("It's happening!")
      DBThing.doSomeDBStuff()
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

My "It's happening!" log statement never shows up, and the stuff that `DBThing.doSomeDBStuff()` is supposed to do never happens. The curious thing is that there are no errors in the console or log files.

How is one supposed to call a controller DBAction from a scheduled runnable? Or How should I rework my scheduler so that this works? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does just the Log message work?  If so, can you successfully retrieve the Object ID of the session object?

Comment: @sdanzig, no the `"It's happening!"` log doesn't work, so I can't log anything from the session either. The `"running the thing!"` log, however, *does* show up... so the the schedule is working fine, but I'm not calling the controller the proper way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the action method will do nothing but return an instance of Action, to actually execute it you would have to call it like play normally does with a request. I would recommend to extract this to non-controller code and call that from your scheduled task instead.

Comment: All the logic is already in non-controller code, so the refactoring should be trivial. The problem is that the non-controller code takes an `(implicit s: Session)` which is required for the DB stuff that it does, so I'm not sure how to handle that. In any case, I will give this a shot when I get home later, and report back.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I had to add `lazy val session = database.createSession()` to `Global.onStart`, and then pass the session around.